# NHibernate v3.3.1.4000 - Lazy Loading of byte[] property from SQLite v1.0.89.0 (x86)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have inherited a class which is as follows: -

```
public class TemplateVersion : Entity
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(TemplateVersion));

    public virtual int VersionNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }

    public virtual byte[] Content { get; set; }

    public virtual string FileExtension { get; set; }
```

I am fairly new to NHibernate but after reading numerous articles that lazy loading for the Content property would just work in version 3??

From what I have seen in NHibernate Profiler so far every time a SELECT is run the Content field is returned which is definitely not what I want:-(

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of properties are never lazy loaded unless you ask for it. See the `lazy` attribute of the `<property>` mapping element (or corresponding in your chosen mapping framework):

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property